# Xcode 6 - Swift - Multiple views on a single-window storyboard cocoa app

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift, storyboard, nsviewcontroller

Just last week I decided to dive into the world of Swift and Xcode development, and as of yesterday I am actively working on a new application.  I have a lot of experience with Java Swing, but working with that is obviously a lot different than working with Apple's fancy interface builders and storyboards.

I am trying to develop a single-window application that has many different views that can be navigated by buttons.  I tried to wrap my head around the way the storyboard works, but even after all my reading of the documentation I don't know really what I'm doing - I'm so used to working in hard code.  It came to the point where I wrote my app's entire network layer just to avoid working with the interface.

Basically I have a set of different NSViewControllers, each with references to a few of their components (buttons, labels, etc) and I want certain buttons to be able to change the current view controller (preferably with a segue animation) to a different one. How can I approach this? I would guess that this isn't hard to achieve, but I am lost.  Any help would be appreciated!

Let me know if I need to submit any code - I do have the basic classes written but nothing relating to this.

Thanks,
-Aidan

Comment: After doing a bit more research it seems that I may have been wrong to write different view controllers for each view that the window can display.  I'm used to Java where there's a single JFrame and then JPanels that can be set to visible when necessary under the frame.  Maybe with the cocoa library I only need one view controller to manage a window's views?

Comment: I realize this is much too late, but for any who stumble onto this question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScB9ZJbkCJI&index=35&list=PLE83F832121568D36